# Laravel - Testar erros no script para retornar determinado status para o AJAX

Tags: ajax, json, laravel

Em uma aplicação em Laravel eu tenho diversos scripts utilizando ajax. Todos esperam uma resposta do script do controller e, se retornar true, eu rodo uma determinada função com o '**success**' do ajax

Exemplo de como estou fazendo:

**script.js**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/teste',
    data: {value:value},
    success: function(data){
        //Alguma função
    }
});
```

**TesteController.php**

```
public function teste(Request $request){
    $value = $request->value;

    /* Alguma função com o value*/

    return response()->json(['success' => true]);
}
```

Porém eu preciso que, caso dê erro, retorne **false**. Só que não faço idéia e como testar isso, eu queria adicionar um teste de errors para todos os scripts(e nem sei se é correto ou necessário ) em diversos casos (**query banco de dados**, trabalhando com **sessão** e etc). Eu conheço o **try/catch** mas nunca usei e dificilmente vejo em algum código alguém usando, então estou meio perdido com isso.

Answer (score 2):

## Primeira opção: O padrão do Laravel

Sinceramente, se fosse eu, eu utilizaria a maneira padrão que o Laravel trata os dados. Quer dizer, quando ocorre algum erro e a requisição é `Ajax`, o `Laravel` retorna `['error' => 'Mensagem da exceção']`.

Ao analisar isso, padronizei que todos meu ajax que retornam com sucesso, teria o seguinte retorno:

```
  return ['error' => false];
```

Assim, você pode tratar todas suas requisições ajax da seguinte maneira:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(response)
      {
           if (response.error)
            {
               return alert("Ocorreu o erro " + response.error);
            }

            alert('Foi feito com sucess');
      }
});
```

## Segunda opção: Costumizar a renderização de exceções:

Se você estiver usando o Laravel 5, dentro da pasta `app/Exceptions` existe uma classe chamada `Handler`. Ele é o manipulador de exceções.

Você pode alterá-lo e adicionar uma verificação que, se for `ajax`, retornará o `['success' => false]` que você deseja.

Para isso, é preciso alterar o método `render`:

```
/**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {

        if ($this->isHttpException($e) && $request->ajax())
        {
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'detail' => (string) $e], 422);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

Aqui nesses artigos, tem boas sugestões de como trabalhar com os erros do `Laravel` através do Ajax:

- [Laravel 5 AJAX Error Handling with Request Classes](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-ajax-error-handling-with-request-classes?page=1)
- [Showing request validation errors when submitting form by ajax](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/showing-request-validation-errors-when-submitting-form-by-ajax)

Comment: E o que eu retorno do controller? Pq se eu não retornar um success-true então o metodo 'success' do ajax não roda.

Comment: Nos exemplos dos links, está ensinando a capturar os erros em Ajax. Quando você retornar `422 status`, você tem que adicionar `error:`  no seu $.ajax