# É possível customizar o retorno da validação do laravel quando utilizo o Request?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Quando utilizo uma requisição post e valído os dados utilizando o Request no Laravel 5.2 via ajax, é retornado automático os dados para o javascript. Gostaria de saber se tem uma forma de eu capturar e customizar esses dados da forma que eu quero para retornar sem ter que utilizar o `validator()`?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127960/4995

Comment: Exemplifique o quer fazer, talvez com isso fique mais claro.

Comment: Você pode criar manualmente a validação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#other-validation-approaches

Comment: Não se trata de criar validação manual, e sim de tratar o retorno das mesmas.

Answer (score 2):

Altere o arquivo `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` e adicione as seguintes linhas:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{

    if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException && $request->ajax())
    {
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'detail' => (string) $e], 422);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Assim, ao verificar se uma exceção é na verdade uma instância de `ValidationException` e a requisição corresponde a uma requisição `XhttpRequest`, você pode emitir uma resposta costumizada, conforme desejado.

Eu já tinha explicado isso nessa resposta:

[Laravel - Testar erros no script para retornar determinado status para o AJAX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127958/laravel-testar-erros-no-script-para-retornar-determinado-status-para-o-ajax/127960#127960)